# Making a circular div expand into its parent on click and reveal content

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I want to create a circular div which expands to full width of its parent div and reveal the content. At least this is how I want it to be experienced by the user. I read the similar topics created but either they did not satisfy my need or I just could not implement them well.
Here is a sketch of what I want it to look like.

[Sketch](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slxsj.png)

And here is what i have done so far.

```js
function revealDetail(detail_no) {
  var i, x;
  x = document.getElementsByClassName("home-insurance");
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  document.getElementById(detail_no).style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
.hero-slider {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hero-slider .slides {
  list-style: none;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.hero-slider .slides:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.hero-slider .slides li {
  min-height: 460px;
  float: left;
  margin-right: -100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.hero-slider .slide-content {
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 25%;
  padding: 30px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 990px) {
  .hero-slider .slide-content {
    width: 50%;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .hero-slider .slide-content {
    width: 100%;
  }
}

.hero-slider .slide-content .slide-title {
  font-size: 35px;
  font-size: 2.1875em;
  font-weight: 300;
  margin-bottom: 30px;
}

.hero-slider .slide-content .slide-title strong {
  color: #0f75bd;
  display: block;
  font-weight: 300;
}

.hero-slider .slide-content p {
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hero-slider .flex-control-nav {
  list-style: none;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -50px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

.hero-slider .flex-control-nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.hero-slider .flex-control-nav li a {
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: #c6c7c7;
  border-radius: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-indent: -99999px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.hero-slider .flex-control-nav li a.flex-active {
  background-color: #0f75bd;
}

.container {
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.container:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .container {
    width: 750px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
  .container {
    width: 970px;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
}

.news-list {
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.vertical-horizontal-center {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.row {
  margin-left: -15px;
  margin-right: -15px;
  *zoom: 1;
}

.row:after {
  content: " ";
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 0;
}

.home-insurance {
  jusitfy-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.home-insurance {
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.home-insurance:hover {
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  transition: 0.5s ease;
}

.h-insurance {
  jusitfy-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #082336;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-color: #082336;
}

.raise {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-top: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

.raise i {
  font-size: 6vw;
  color: #fff;
}

.raise span {
  color: #fff;
  margin-top: 15px;
}

.text-center {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div class="hero hero-slider">

    <ul class="slides">
      <li>
        <div class="container news-list vertical-horizontal-center" id="insurance-container">
          <div class="col" style="background-color:black;display:none;height:100vh;" id="d0"></div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:black;display:none;height:100vh;" id="d1"></div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:black;display:none;height:100vh;" id="d2"></div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:black;display:none;height:100vh;" id="d3"></div>
          <div class="col" style="background-color:black;display:none;height:100vh;" id="d4"></div>


          <div class="row">
            <div class="col smth home-insurance">
              <div class="h-insurance raise text-center " style="height:10vw;width:10vw;" onclick="revealDetail('d0')">
                <i class="icon-credit-card-hand text-center"></i>
              </div>
              <span>Content0<span>



          </div>
          <div class="col smth home-insurance">
            <div class="h-insurance raise text-center " style="height:10vw;width:10vw;" onclick="revealDetail('d1')">
              <i class="icon-credit-card-hand text-center"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Content1<span>



          </div>
          <div class="col smth home-insurance">
            <div class="h-insurance raise text-center " style="height:10vw;width:10vw;" onclick="revealDetail('d2')">
              <i class="icon-credit-card-hand text-center"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Content2<span>



          </div>
          <div class="col smth home-insurance">
            <div class="h-insurance raise text-center " style="height:10vw;width:10vw;" onclick="revealDetail('d3')">
              <i class="icon-credit-card-hand text-center"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Content3<span>



          </div>
          <div class="col smth home-insurance">
            <div class="h-insurance raise text-center " style="height:10vw;width:10vw;" onclick="revealDetail('d4')">
              <i class="icon-credit-card-hand text-center"></i>
            </div>
            <span>Content4<span>



          </div>
          <div class="col-12" id="d00" style="display:none;height:75vh;background-color:black">
            <span style="color:#fff;">Kapat</span>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </li>








    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- .hero-slider -->

</body>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Okstrok/hsckz8nf/29/

Answer (score 0):

1. You may first try to remove the padding from your ul element:

```css
.hero-slider .slides {
    padding: 0;
}
```

2. Also try to give to the inner div that in the li element:

```css
.container {
    padding:0;
    max-width: inherit;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have managed to kind of achieve the animation using jquery animate.
I have added a attribute `dnumber` to the element identified by class `h-insurance` and removed  'onclick()' function

```
$('.h-insurance').on('click', function() {
  let dnumber = '#' + $(this).attr('dnumber');
  // hide all home-insurance div tags
  $('.home-insurance').hide();
  // show only the home-insurance div (circle) on which animation is required
  $(this).closest('.home-insurance').show();
  // hide caption of the circle
  $(this).closest('.home-insurance').find('span').hide();

  // animate the circle with time of 1000ms
  $(this).animate({
    height: '100vh',
    width: '100%'
  }, 1000);

  // hide the circle and show the display block after 1000ms
  // this code executes after the circle animation
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.home-insurance').hide();
    $(dnumber).show(1);
  }, 1000);

});
```

Check the jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/g73npm21/16/

Comment: Thanks that looks really close to what I intended to do. But I couldn't manage the transition from circle to rectangle. I want to make it look much more clean somehow.